# Character (trace) of swap operator of $S_{2}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$S_{2}$ is the permutation group of 2 objects, i.e. $S_{2} = \{I,S\}$. $S$ is the swap operator i am asking: $S\left|i\right>\left|j\right> = \left|j\right>\left|i\right>$.

Let the representation (homomorphism) be $\rho = S_2 \rightarrow \text{span}\{\left|i\right>\left|j\right>\}$, $i,j = 1,....d$.

I know that the trace of identity operator is $d^2$ (all entry 1 in the matrix). But Why is the trace (character) of the swap operator be d?

---

$\left|i\right>\left|j\right>$ is the tensor product of $\left|i\right>$ and $\left|j\right>$, each is of dimension $d$.

Answer (score 1):

The trace of a permutation operator is the number of basis vectors that are mapped to themselves.

Now the permutation opreator maps $|i\rangle|j\rangle$ ro $|j\rangle|i\rangle$. Thus $|i\rangle|j\rangle$ is mapped to itself exactly if $i=j$, that is, if the vector has the form $|i\rangle|i\rangle$. There are exactly $d$ such vectors.